# Webpack 1.14 possibly not converting ES6 to ES5

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am working on a MS Word add-in (basically just a React app injected into Word) with a very limited ability of debugging so I'm not 100 % this is the issue. I am trying to use this package: https://github.com/dphilipson/broken-loop as an alternative to webworkers. I have this in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
loaders: [
// ...
{
  test: /\.(js|jsx|ts)$/,
  include: [paths.appSrc, '/node_modules/broken-loop/dist'], // like this?
  loader: 'babel',
  query: {
    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0']
  }
},
// ...
]
```

But I still get 'Invalid character' issue on Windows Word (which uses IE11 engine), while the code works fine on Mac and on the online version of Word (tried Chrome and FF). My best guess is this is a ES6 issue in IE11.

How can I edit my webpack config to make sure the package is translated to ES5, as well?

EDIT:

I get the error by just doing this in my project:

```
import { Looper } from 'broken-loop';
const looper = new Looper();
```

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code, both what you've written and what webpack outputs. May be something else

Comment: Can you provide the `.babelrc` config file? Is there any reason you use Webpack 1 instead of 3 or 4?

Comment: @phuzi please see edit above. you can see more of the looper code on the link at the beginning of my post

Comment: @ChrisR there is no .babelrc in this project; everything is in webpack.config.js. The reason this is Webpack 1 is very trivial: up until this point, everything worked fine. This is an ejected create-react-app and when it was created, Webpack 1 was the version shipped with it.

Comment: While not really helpful I would say that you just upgrade and migrate to webpack 3. I just did that myself a few weeks ago for a fairly large project and while it was quite nifty, I had it upgraded and running within a few days. Webpack 3 is way faster and more stable than 1 was. For me this helped with many things that were bugging me with webpack.

Comment: @DavidFariña thanks for the tip. Yes, it may be prudent to migrate to ver. 3 first and then see what's happening with this issue.